# How efficient are Thermomelectric generators

Tags: thermistor

How effective is a thermoelectric generator, as in how much electricity would it provide over a period of time vs other methods of energy? is it useful and practical at all? an idea of how you can reference this to me could be like how much electricity can it produce in a day for a city.

Comment: I expect the answer to be a variation on _too broad_.

Comment: What have you researched so far? What is the fuel source you are considering? Is this country specific? Some use geo-thermal energy as a source so efficiency may become a lower priority...

Comment: Effective or efficient? They mean different things.

Comment: If you ask about a city-wide installation you should mention where you found that idea. Spontaneously this sounds crazy, so you probably misunderstood something. Therefore I'm voting to close as unclear, because it's hard to tell what you actually think a thermoelectric generator is.

Comment: When you Googled "thermoelectric generator efficiency", what did you get? Did you even look at the Wiki article. I'm voting to close based on no effort at research whatsoever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no research done. The Wiki article provides a number.

Comment: Reasonably well answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/285498/3288)

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably well answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/285498/3288)

The upper absolute maximum limit is the Carnot efficiency
= Delta_T / Thot.

Where

- Delta_T is (Temperature on hot side - temperature on cold side) and
- Thot is the ABSOLUTE temperature of the hot side
  =~ 273 + Thot_Celsius.

So for eg A 100 C Delta T and hot side of 120C
Z_Carnot = Carnot efficiency = 100/(273 + 120) =~ 25%.
Actual efficiency will be a modest fraction of Z_Carnot
eg 10% absolute (= 10/25 = 40% of Carnot) would be good
and 5% absolute would be more likely .

Manufacturers data sheets for TEGs invariably provide performance data for various Thot and delta T values.

[Waste heat TEG generation paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301841055_Efficiency_calculation_of_thermoelectric_generator_by_extracting_waste_heat_for_practical_applications)

[Useful](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a538107.pdf)

[Some value](https://www.electrochem.org/dl/interface/fal/fal08/fal08_p54-56.pdf)

[Many leads here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&ei=kczpWpCIIoWx8wXTj7CAAg&q="thermoelectric+generator+efficiency"&oq="thermoelectric+generator+efficiency"&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l6j0j0i30k1l3.4343.6712.0.7693.6.6.0.0.0.0.222.1284.2-6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.652...35i39k1.0.SeXv-6xjSzU)

[Numerous images](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q="thermoelectric+generator+efficiency"&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKppvyn-faAhXKfbwKHYamDyYQsAR6BAgAEHQ&biw=1344&bih=696&dpr=1.25) - relevance varies. Each linked to a web page.

Answer (score 0):

A thermoelectric generator, that is thermocouple or Peltier based, is very inefficient compared to mechanical generators. If you have a reasonable temperature difference, then running a Stirling engine + generator would be far more efficient.

One situation where it could be effective would be where you have otherwise waste heat, from a gas-lamp or the hot exhaust of a car. Another is for a very low power application where the convenience or necessity of no moving parts outweighed the poor efficiency. As Mr. Felthry points out in comments, they are used in [RTGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), in a rather special application.

Producing electricity for a city is a non-starter.

Comment: They're also used in RTGs! Where it's really the only option.

Comment: The only application i ever played with this was making a heat sink/fan combo that sat on top of a wood stove to power a little fan that circulated the wood stove's heat. I thought that it was pretty neat idea for my off grid cabin.

Comment: @drtechno excellent matching of the power level, timing of its availability, and situation!